# Tcp sampler end of line byte value in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2

I have TCP server which will be sending dynamic responses i.e. approve or decline or hold. Now I am trying to load test it using jmeters TCP sampler. In this case how can I give dynamic EOL byte value in TCP sampler. If response is approve or decline it should be byte value of character e and if the response is hold it should be the byte value of d. How can i give dynamic EOL byte value.

Answer (score 0):

If this is really what you're looking for you can define EOL byte value in form of a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) like `${EOL}` and amend this variable value according to your test scenario.

---

However I strongly doubt that TCP server you're testing changes EOL byte value depending on the request status, I would rather expect that it provides different response which you can verify using [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved)

Also be aware that you can amend response status via `tcp.status.prefix` and `tcp.status.suffix` JMeter properties so you can use them in order to amend Response Code so you will be able to see how many requests had response code `e` and how many had `d` once your test finishes.